# Passing kwargs through mutliple levels of functions, unpacking some of them but passing all of them

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a lot of functions within functions and a lot of variables because I'm making modular 2D drawings. For that purpose I want to be able to pass a kwargs dict down into several layers of functions. As an example:

```py
mydict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

def bar(b, c, **kwargs):
    print("bar b=" + str(b))
    print("bar c=" + str(c))
    print("bar kwargs: ", kwargs)


def foo(a, b, **kwargs):
    print("foo a=" + str(a))
    print("foo b=" + str(b))
    print("foo kwargs: ", kwargs)
    bar(b, **kwargs)

foo(**mydict)
```

This returns:

```
foo a=1
foo b=2
foo kwargs:  {'c': 3}
bar b=2
bar c=3
bar kwargs:  {}
```

This works nicely because it catches all the kwargs I don't need. However, I need to explicitly pass kwargs that I unpacked in `foo` to `bar`. I would like to pass the whole `mydict` down into `bar` as I did in `foo` while keeping it readable.

The only way I can think of doing that right now is by passing `mydict` twice, where I only unpack it once and catch any unused kwargs in `**_`, which doesn't seem nice.

```py
mydict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

def bar(mydict, b, c, **_):
    print("bar b=" + str(b))
    print("bar c=" + str(c))
    print("bar \'kwargs\': ", mydict)

def foo(mydict, a, b, **_):
    print("foo a=" + str(a))
    print("foo b=" + str(b))
    print("foo \'kwargs\': ", mydict)
    bar(mydict, **mydict)

foo(mydict, **mydict)
```

Which returns

```
foo a=1
foo b=2
foo 'kwargs':  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
bar b=2
bar c=3
bar 'kwargs':  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Why not just pass mydict once as the only parameter, get the parameters you need out of it (raise a ValueError if they are missing), and then pass it along to the next function.  Eliminate the argument unpacking entirely.

Comment: Alternatively, you could reinsert the local parameters back into kwargs before calling the next function, and then only every call each function by passing (**kwargs) with no positional parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Let the functions take only **kwargs:

```
mydict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

def bar(**kwargs):
    print("bar b=" + str(kwargs['b']))
    print("bar c=" + str(kwargs['c']))
    print("bar kwargs: ", kwargs)


def foo(**kwargs):
    print("foo a=" + str(kwargs['a']))
    print("foo b=" + str(kwargs['b']))
    print("foo kwargs: ", kwargs)
    bar(**kwargs)

foo(**mydict)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you've correctly identified a code smell in the architecture of your code.

##### (Not Recommended) Function for extracting variables from kwargs

There are inbuilt methods for a dict

```py
b = mydict.get("b") # or mydict['b']
```

or maybe with a more bespoke function

```py
def get_b_c(b, c, **_):
    return b, c

def bar(**kwargs):
    b,c = get_b_c(**kwargs)
    print("bar b=" + str(b))
    print("bar c=" + str(c))
    print("bar \'kwargs\': ", kwargs)
```

##### Using a class

The problem you have identified is needing to repeatedly pass in the same arguments to do some processing on them, this can be simplified by using an object and some attached methods. The arguments are parsed only once in the initialization.

```py
class MyDrawing:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.a = kwargs.get('a')
        self.b = kwargs.get('b')
        self.c = kwargs.get('c')
        self.kwargs = kwargs # you probably don't need it, but here to match your example

    def bar(self):
        print("bar b=" + str(self.b))
        print("bar c=" + str(self.c))
        print("bar \'kwargs\': ", self.kwargs)

    def foo(self):
        print("foo a=" + str(self.a))
        print("foo b=" + str(self.b))
        print("foo \'kwargs\': ", self.kwargs)
        self.bar()

drawing = MyDrawing(**mydict)
drawing.foo()
```

Comment: Given that the original code considers the non-`**kwargs` arguments mandatory, you really shouldn't be using `kwargs.get(key)` here; `kwargs[key]` will at least raise an exception when the argument is missing, rather than silently substituting `None`.

Comment: Note that the "bespoke function" helper can be nested inside the function it is helping, and then you can give it the same name, and then if a developer misses one of the required arguments, you get almost exactly the error message and traceback that you would get from the original normally written function.

Answer (score 3):

```py
@magic_copying_kwargs
def foo(a, b, /, **kwargs):
    ...
```

where the `magic_copying_kwargs` decorator is defined like this:

```py
import inspect

def magic_copying_kwargs(function):
    parameters = inspect.signature(function).parameters
    def _wrapper_function(**kwargs):
        args = []
        for name in parameters:
            if name != 'kwargs':
                try:
                    args.append(kwargs[name])
                except KeyError:
                    raise TypeError(f'missing a required argument: {name!r}')
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapper_function
```

This assumes Python >=3.8, which has positional-only arguments.

Note that this answer slightly differs from the question - it will not remove arguments from `kwargs` once they're used. Instead of manually passing through `b` as in the question's example, it would just come through in `kwargs`. I wrote it this way because it's more flexible - you can nest calls in any order with any argument names, and every function in the call stack with argument `a` will get `a` from the original `kwargs`. If you prefer the behavior in the question's example, use `kwargs.pop(name)` instead of `kwargs[name]`.

Comment: i had a similar approach in my code, the problem (and the reason why I came here) is that this doesn't work if a nested function, e.g. `function2', is called from inside `function`. In this case the parameters of `function2` are not detected by inspect.

Comment: @Vincenzooo `function2` needs to also have the same decorator applied to it. If you don't control the definition of `function2`, you can always decorate it locally (instead of `function2(b, **kwargs)`, call `magic_copying_kwargs(function2)(b, **kwargs)`).

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind some extra junk passing around, you can use [locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) at the beginning of your function to collect your arguments into a new dict and update it with the kwargs, and later pass that one to the next function

```
mydict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

def bar(b, c, **kwargs):
    print("bar b=" + str(b))
    print("bar c=" + str(c))
    print("bar kwargs: ", kwargs)


def foo(a, b, **kwargs):
    new_arg = locals()|kwargs
    print("foo a=" + str(a))
    print("foo b=" + str(b))
    print("foo kwargs: ", kwargs)
    bar(**new_arg)

foo(**mydict)
```

which result into

```
foo a=1
foo b=2
foo kwargs:  {'c': 3}
bar b=2
bar c=3
bar kwargs:  {'a': 1, 'kwargs': {'c': 3}}
```

for older version of python `locals()|kwargs` is equivalent to:

```
new_arg = {**locals(),**kwargs}`
```

or

```
new_arg = dict(locals())
new_arg.update(kwargs)
```

Comment: Note that this will add a `kwargs` kwarg to your kwargs. Of course the solution is to do `del new_kwargs['kwargs']` afterwards. (Also, I would maybe just do `kwargs |= locals()` because it seems more similar to saying what is meant; "re-add these into my kwargs".)

Comment: @mtraceur yep, likewise if `a` also fall in the category of extra junk it can be deal the same...